# An zero upper-sum on a function with a discontinuous function

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

For a Reimann integrabl function $f(x) \geq 0$ on $[a,b]$, I'm asked to...

> Prove that if $\int_a^b f(x)~dx = 0$ and $f$ is continuous, then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$.

and, immediately after to...

> Find a counterexample which shows that the conclusion of part (b) may not hold if the hypothesis of continuity is removed.

I feel as if there's something key I'm missing here—all of my "proofs" for the first question are independent of whether or not $f$ is continuous. Even worse, given a constant function with a single discontinuous point—I can show that $\int_a^b f(x)~dx$ converges to the value of the integral if one were to omit said point. by taking intervals in the partition to be sufficiently small.

What does continuity have to do with this? I'm really struggling to find a connection.

Comment: Consider $f(x) = \frac{|x|}{x}$. Let $a = -1$ and $b = 1$. Then $\int_a^b f(x) dx = 0$, but $f(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: I think this is missing a hypothesis: is it given that $f(x) \geq 0$?

Comment: Oh, sorry! Yes. $f(x) \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint: this is MUCH easier to prove (in my opinion anyway) by proving the contrapositive. Assume $f(x)\neq 0$ for some $c \in [a, b]$, and then take a small epsilon neighborhood about $f(c)$... THEN it should become clear where continuity becomes involved.

(An aside: you also noted why it matters in your post! If $f(x)$ is identically $0$ save a finite number of points on $[a,b]$, then $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) = 0$ but $f(x)$ is not identically zero!)